# Como popular select com 2 paramêtros json

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Eu estou fazendo um formulário, e não encontrei nada parecido nas pesquisas que fiz.

Eu tenho o código http://jsfiddle.net/rubensoul/xdmz35oy/3/ estou conseguindo popular eles normalmente,

Ao selecionar uma data ele popula a região, ao popular a região popula um profissional, e ao popular o profissional, ele popula o horário.

No entanto, preciso que selecionar um checkbox de 'tipo de exame complementar', ele traga informação do JSON de profissional e também de checkbox para o select de horário. O que eu preciso é criar uma array que tenha os dois ids, tanto profissional quanto checkbox, em horário.

eu preciso então, que os 2 parametros (profissional e (tipo de exame) fossem enviados para a mesma array, e voltasse para o select (horarios) estou usando um switch case de json

Tenho que passar o parâmetro de checkbox e ele interagir com o array de profissional, e atualizar o horario, é basicamente isso

```
 <?php 

 header('Content-type: text/json'); $retorno = array();

 switch($_POST['profissional']) {    case '21': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",  
         41 => "18h30",

       );
       break;    case '24': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",  
          42 => "18h50",

       );
       break;

    case '27': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",   
          43 => "20h30",

       );
       break;    case '30': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",   
          44 => "20h00",

       );
       break;
         case '33': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",     
          45 => "22h45",

       );
       break;

             case '35': // 
       $retorno = array(         0 => "Selecione um horário",   
          46 => "22h00",

       );
       break; }


 echo json_encode($retorno);

 ?>
```

// chamada para checkbox

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: text/json');
$retorno = array();

switch($_POST['inlineCheckbox1'])
{
   case 'option1': // regiao 1
      $retorno = array(
         0 => "Selecione um horário (checkbox)",  
         91 => "18h30",
         95 => "19h30",

      );
      break;
   case 'option2': // regiao 2
      $retorno = array(
         0 => "Selecione um horário (checkbox)",  
         92 => "18h50",
         99 => "22h50",


      );
      break;

   case 'option3': // regiao 2
      $retorno = array(
         0 => "Selecione um horário (checkbox)",   
         93 => "20h30",
         97 => "22h30",

      );
      break;

}


echo json_encode($retorno);

?>
```

Como posso fazer essa mudança no array para receber os 2 paramêtros?

Será que alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se percebi bem queres que quando o utilizador selecionar um checkbox vá um pedido para o servidor que retorna um JSON e queres que essa informação vá para o select "Horários Disponíveis"... é isso? O que não está a funcionar? algum erro? No AJAX estás a enviar `data: {inlineCheckbox1: $("#inlineCheckbox1").val()},` mas não vejo no PHP onde estás a usar esse `inlineCheckbox1`.

Comment: Olá, @Sergio consegue me ajudar novamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar para o javascript usando mais de um valor use:

```
data: {regiao: $("#regiao").val(),
profissional: $("#profissional").val()}
```

O javascript enviará então os dois valores ao mesmo tempo para a página solicitada. Não é possível utilizar ajax para enviar para duas páginas ao mesmo tempo.

Recomendo também utilizar apenas um $(document).ready() e colocar todos os conteúdos unidos, assim código ficaria mais legível também:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#regiao').bind('change', function(){
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
     url: "teste2.php",
     data: {regiao: $("#regiao").val()},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(json){
        var options = "";
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
           options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $("#profissional").html(options);
     }
   });
 });
// AQUI É O CHECKBOX

$('#inlineCheckbox1').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "teste4.php",
     data: {inlineCheckbox1: $("#inlineCheckbox1").val()},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(json){
        var options = "";
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
           options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $("#horarios").html(options);
     }
  });
});

// AQUI É O PROFISSIONAL

 $('#profissional').bind('change', function(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "teste3.php",
     data: {profissional: $("#profissional").val()},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(json){
        var options = "";
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
           options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $("#horarios").html(options);
     }
     });
   });
});
```

Resposta ao comentário:

Sim, vc pode interceptar no javascript os valores selecionados antes de enviar para o ajax de várias maneiras. Um truque que vc pode usar é modificar a tag name de todas as checkboxes para option e os valores delas para 1 e 2 e 3. modifique o id delas para clin, derm e odont. Assim você pode enviar apenas o seguinte para o jquery:

```
data: {regiao: $("#regiao").val(),
    profissional: $("#profissional").val(),
    tipo: [ $("#clin").val(), $("#derm ").val(), $("#odont").val()]
}
```

Aí você precisará desmembrar o tipo no php através de split.

ou

```
data: {regiao: $("#regiao").val(),
    profissional: $("#profissional").val(),
    clin: $("#clin")[0].checked?$("#clin").val():'',
    derm: $("#derm")[0].checked?$("#derm").val():'',
    odont: $("#odont")[0].checked?$("#odont").val():''
 }
```

Aí você terá uma variável para cada checkbox

Comment: Certo, fiz a mudança que sugeriu, http://jsfiddle.net/rubensoul/xdmz35oy/10/ mas como eu faço para o array json reconhecer os 2 parâmetros? devo pegar a id de profissional e também de checkbox, e como devo colocar o checkbox para atualizar pelo json?  "  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" name="option1"> Clínico" algo assim [] ?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver essa questão, com base no que disse, mas agora eu tenho que deixar esse input de checkbox dinamico, ou seja, cada um que for selcionado, tem que ter um valor diferente, você consegue me ajudar? 

http://jsfiddle.net/rubensoul/r92o6fb4/1/

Comment: certo, eu usei um id por fora do checkbox, e deu certo, só que não estou conseguindo passar o value de cada checkbox, eu usei o:
var data = new Array();
$("input[name='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i) {
 data.push($(this).val());
});
 antes do $ajax, o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Alterei a resposta, esqueci de testar se ela está selecionada ou não. O [0] na frente do jquery transforma um objeto jquery em objeto javascript puro

Comment: eu usei mais ou menos o que disse, da uma olhada http://jsfiddle.net/rubensoul/r92o6fb4/2/ eu só preciso agora, que ele envie o valor do checkbox para o json (php), do jeito que coloquei é o certo?

Comment: verifique http://jsfiddle.net/r92o6fb4/3/, acho que é o que você precisa.
Teste do lado do Php se o $_REQUEST["clin"] != '' e os demais. Troque o switch para ifs em cada um destes requests e trate-os um a um. Como vocÊ utilizou checkbox ao invés de options, pode ser selecionada mais de uma opção, então você terá de testar as três opções

Comment: Entendi, é que eu preciso que esse valor seja dinamico, eu coloquei o seguinte código: checkbox:$($("#checkbox input")[0]).prop("checked")?$($("#checkbox input")[0]).val():'', ele trouxe o valor, legal e funcionou, mas como tem 3 e poderá ter mais campos dependendo do cliente, precisaria que atendesse todos os inputs do checkbox, por isso eu coloquei os name de checkbox []